# PHP - Json_encode how to add variable to database selection and passing to Json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to get the data from MySQL database, add a variable near it and then show it in JSON format.

The output should look like this:

```
{"items":[{"cinemaname":"Cinema name","logo":"upload/cinemaname.png","distance":"103"},{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 2","logo":"upload/cinemaname2.png","distance":"23"}]}
```

The table does not consist of the distance, the distance should be calculated and added manually in the code.

The code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"some query here");

while($rowm = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $all[]= $rowm;
}

$alldata = array('items'=>$all);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($alldata);
}
```

How can I add the distance to the output?

I tried this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"some query here");

while($rowm = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //here is calculation of a distance = $distance

    $all[]= $rowm.'distance=>'.$distance;    
}

$alldata = array('items'=>$all);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($alldata);
}
```

Currently, the script outputs this:

```
{"items":[{"cinemaname":"Cinema name","logo":"upload/cinemaname.png"},{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 2","logo":"upload/cinemaname2.png"}]}
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
{"items":[{"cinemaname":"Cinema name","logo":"upload/cinemaname.png","distance":"103"},{"cinemaname":"Cinema name 2","logo":"upload/cinemaname2.png","distance":"23"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rowm` is an array so using strings concatenation via `.` will not work ! please try this:

```
$rowm['distance'] = $distance;
$all[] = $rowm;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot Ismail!You are awesome :))

Comment: Can you help me with this problem please :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184358/php-get-data-from-database-compare-it-to-variable-and-sort-by-less-value

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `items`");

while($rowm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $all['items'][] = array_values($rowm);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($all);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"some query here");

while($rowm = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $distance={calc of distance};
    $all[]=array(
            "cinemaname"=>$rowm['name']
        ,   "logo"=>$rowm['logo']
        ,   "distance"=>$distance); 
}
$alldata = array('items'=>$all);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($alldata);
```