# PHP - get data from database compare it to variable and sort by less value

Tags: php, mysql, location, latitude-longitude

Script should:

1. Take latitude and logitude from database of each cinema with while()
2. Compare to location of a user
3. Get the output in kilometers
4. Show all of them based on less kilometers

Everything is solved on the script down below, only number 4 is not implemented.

I have no idea how to compare every item of while() loop and show everything in the ascending order.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cinemas WHERE city='$city'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$lat1 = $_GET['lat']; //latitude of a user
$lon1= $_GET['lon']; //longitude of a user
$lat2 = $row['latitude'];  //latitude of a cinema
$lon2 = $row['longitude']; //longitude of a cinema

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = $miles * 1.609344; //calculated the distance between them

$distance = substr($unit,0,4)." km"; //output of a distance


  echo $distance;
   ?> 

      //here is the data about movie

<div id="time"><?php echo $row3['showone']; // timing of a movie ?></div>



}}
?>
```

Script out is:

```
20 km 
movie information

5 km
movie information

45 km 
movie information

1 km 
movie information
```

I need to show them in ascending order.

Comment: There are many questions that show how to do this in MySQL.  But you want to do it in PHP?

Comment: You need to store all the values into an array before displaying them all. there are sorting commands such as ksort or sort to do this before output

Comment: @RickJames well explain me please how to do in mysql then?
Forbs can you describe a little with code please

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort()` with your distance.

```
echo sort($distance);
```